# Is it possible to grab an external image and send it over a REST API via Javascript only?

Tags: javascript, image, parse-platform

I have a form where users can paste the external url of an image. Is it possible via javascript to go and grab that file and then POST it to a REST API? I'm using parse.com for the rest api.

Comment: Why do you want the client to download the file?

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing. The app is all client side (backbone.js + parse.com). I already have an uploader working, so I figured if I could just get the client the file somehow, then I could upload to parse.com the same way I currently am.

Comment: You can use `javascript` to fetch an image from a `url` [like this one](http://jsfiddle.net/ZF3qe/1/).

Comment: @SheikhHeera thank you! I think I can get it working with this

Answer (score 2):

> … external url of an image. Is it possible via javascript to go and grab that file …

No. This is prevented by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you will not be allowed to access it. Just post the URL of it to your REST api and fetch it on the server side.

While you cannot access the file or data associated with it, of course you can display it by embedding via an `<img>` element.

Answer (score 1):

One way or another, the image will first have to be pulled onto your server due to restrictions on working with cross-origin resources. Once you have done this you can use my elaborate example to convert the image into `Base64` and then into a `JSON` string ready to be transported via `POST` to your `REST` server:

```
<input id="urlText" />
<input id="sendData" type="submit" />
<img id="img" src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png" />
<script>
var imgElem = document.getElementById('img');
$('#urlText').keyup(function(){
   $('#img').attr('src',$('#urlText').val());
});

$('#sendData').click(function(){
var imgData = JSON.stringify(getBase64Image(imgElem));
  $.ajax({
  url: 'http://url.com/rest/api',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: imgData,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
  });
});

function getBase64Image(imgElem) {
// imgElem must be on the same server otherwise a cross-origin error will be thrown "SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18"
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = imgElem.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = imgElem.clientHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imgElem, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
</script>
```

My [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jasdeepkhalsa/L5HmW/) is here.